# Vuejs 2 prop error

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I am new to vue and what I'm trying to do is create an date input mask with this jquery plugin: [jQuery-Mask-Plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

I created a vue component like this:

```
<template>
    <input type="text" name="" class="form-control date">
</template>

<script>
    require('./../jquery.mask.min.js');
    export default {

        mounted: function () {
            $('.date').mask('00/00/0000');
            console.log('name ' + this.input-name);
        },

        props: ['input-name']

    }
</script>
```

I also tried:

```
props: ['input_name']
```

In another component and in a blade file I am calling it like this:

```
<date-input :input-name="delivery_date"></date-input>
```

When I run it in the browser I get this error:

[Vue warn]: Property or method "delivery_date" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. 
(found in )

Why do I get this error?

The console.log gives me undefined.

Also, how do I put the value I send (delivery_date) into the input name in the template?
I tried:

```
<input type="text" name="{{ input-name }}" class="form-control date">
```

But that broke npm run dev.

Comment: Use `props: [inputName]` and `:input-name="delivery_date"`. You do `:input-name="delivery_date"` and it is correct. Put `delivery_date` in `data` in your parent component.

Comment: Thx, but this gives me this error: app.js:12941 Uncaught ReferenceError: inputName is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:12941)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (app.js:12944)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:33918)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:11463)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:44695)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at app.js:66

Comment: This works:
props: ['inputName'],
<date-input input-name="delivery_date"></date-input>
But to display the value:
This works: <span>{{ inputName }}</span>
This doesn't:
<input type="text" name="{{ inputName }}> or 
<input type="text" :name="{{ inputName }}" or 
<input type="text" v-bind:name="{{ inputName }} or 
<input type="text" name="@{{ inputName }}"

Comment: Use `<input type="text" :name="inputName">`. In fact you can put every javascript code when you use `v-bind` or the shortcut `:`

Comment: Ok, this solved the problem:

Calling: <date-input input-name="delivery_date"></date-input>

Reading:

<input type="text" :name="inputName" class="form-control date">
Thank you very much!